# Equivalent Binary Trees Exercise, achieving the "concurrency"

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm solving the exercise from *A Tour of Go*, [Equivalent Binary Tree](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/8).
This exercise requires one to implement a `Walk` function which is supposed to walk a tree and send all values orderly from the tree to a channel.

The exercise statement states:

> ... We'll use Go's concurrency and channels to write a simple solution.

Reading that line, I think it is challenging to implement the `Walk` in a way that it launches a goroutine for each left/right subtree and enabling the `Walk` to run faster (regarding time complexity) than non-concurrent version. Let me explain in more detail with codes.

This is my early code for `Walk`:

```golang
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    defer close(ch)
    if t == nil { return }
    
    lch, rch := make(chan int), make(chan int)
    go Walk(t.Left, lch)
    for v := range lch { ch <- v }

    ch <- t.Value

    go Walk(t.Right, rch)
    for v := range rch { ch <- v }

    return
}
```

It surely uses goroutines, but effectively isn't different from just traversing without goroutines because the ealry `for v := range lch { ... }` delays `go Walk(t.Right, rch)` until it ends.

It does not make any difference to move up `go Walk(t.Right, rch)`:

```golang
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    defer close(ch)
    if t == nil { return }
    
    lch, rch := make(chan int), make(chan int)
    go Walk(t.Left, lch)
    go Walk(t.Right, rch)

    for v := range lch { ch <- v }
    ch <- t.Value
    for v := range rch { ch <- v }
}
```

[image: a tree with colored nodes]

`go Walk(t.Left, lch)` walks along the entire left subtree (rooted on the blue) and values sent from `lch` are *received immediately*.

`go Walk(t.Right, rch)` tries to walk along as well but *gets blocked* as `ch <- t.Value` on the left-most node (the red) of the right subtree does so and propagates the blocking. This state persists until `for v := range rch { ch <- v }` is reached.

**My question** :
How to implement `Walk` in a way that goroutines (corresponding to left or right) avoid being blocked by `ch <- t.Value` as much as possible?

Comment: Remember, `go Somefunc()` is running `Somefunc` in a new goroutine.

Comment: Once your code hits the `range { } ` block, it'll never leave. `range`'s are great for dealing with channels, but think of it as an infinite loop until you call `close` on the channel.

Comment: @NateH06 it does get closed, in the `defer` on the first line.

Comment: This question is [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405734/could-my-closed-question-be-re-opened-i-have-edited-it). If anyone of the close voters is willing to share what they are missing in the question or how it is unclear, that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A buffer (e.g. a buffered channel) is required for the values from the right subtree as they must persist until the values preceding those (`<-lch` and `t.Value`) are consumed.

Preparing a buffer for a subtree, the size of which are unknown, has several implications

- If a buffered channel, `make(chan int, N)`, is used, choosing `N` is critical. If `N` happens to be too small for a subtree, the goroutine for the subtree blocks too soon. If it is too large, the memory is unnecessarily wasted.
- Implementing the custom channel with auto-resizing buffer may be one solution, but it introduces additional complexity and overhead. I don’t know whether the penalties neutralize the performance gain or not. It depends on how the custom channel manages its internal buffer or how the pool of those are managed.

In my opinion, **there is no simple and universal solution** for this kind of problem, "traverse a random, unknown tree with concurrency squeezed out".